# Where is Psyduck in Pokemon Moon?

Tags: pokemon-sun-moon

The Pokedex indicates that Psyduck is somewhere in the Oricorio Meadow, but after hours of searching there and the Seaward Cave, I still haven't found him. Is the Pokedex wrong about its location or do I just need to keep looking?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to Serebii, Psyduck can be found in:

- *Brooklet Hill* (grass and surfing)
- *Malie Garden* (grass)
- *Seaward Cave* (surfing)
- *Ten Carat Hill* (surfing).

For further details, see [here](http://www.serebii.net/pokedex-sm/location/054.shtml#x).

Answer (score 0):

It's best to press Y on the pokedex and have your 'position indicator' (the happy face) be right on top of the black pokemon symbol, because, since there are usually multiple grassy spots in an area, not all the grassy spots have that pokemon.

This doesn't necessarily answer the question, but the pokedex is correct. You just have to find the right grassy spot.